# Inversion of a one-dimensional dynamic array into an N-dimensional

Tags: c++

Help to understand the creation of the array: the task is to dynamically build an array with an arbitrary number of measurements and their arbitrary depth.
The input receives a one-dimensional array `int arr []` with an arbitrary (n) number of elements. For e.g we can create one-dimensional array like `int arr= new int[size]`, we can create two-dimensional array `int **arr= new int*[size]` and so on, but how can we create it when we dont'n know how many dimensions? I just started to learn C++ so I can't use object-oriented programming and vectors

Comment: You can think of dimensions as of matter of indexing.

Comment: You mean I can create one-dimensional array and make size equal size of for e.g. 4 dimensional array?

Comment: For example you can create array with 6 items. You may think of it as containing 1D array with 6 items, as 2D array 2x3 or 3x2 items, as 3D array with 1x2x3 or 1x3x2 items, etc.

Comment: A 2D to 1 D mapping looks like `X * Number_of_Ys + Y`. 3D looks like `(X * Number_of_Ys + Y) * Number_of_Zs + Z`. See the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of these commenters suggested, one thing you can do is create a large one-dimensional array instead of a multi-dimensional array, e.g.

```
int *arr = new int[wLength * zLength * yLength * xLength];
```

and instead of indexing this way `arr[w][z][y][x]` index like this: `arr[w * zLength * yLength * xLength + z * yLength * xLength + y * xLength + x]`.

Of course if you want the type of N-dimensional arrays (given N is a constant expression), you can use a template with an overload like this:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N-1>::Type *Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 0> {
    typedef T Type;
};
```

With that definition, you get these types:

```
std::is_same<NDimensionalArray<char, 1>::Type, char*>::value; // true
std::is_same<NDimensionalArray<char, 2>::Type, char**>::value; // true
std::is_same<NDimensionalArray<char, 3>::Type, char***>::value; // true
```

Encapsulated N-dimensional array class, for newing, deleting, and indexing into N-dimensional arrays, left as an exercise.  (Hint: Use a `std::array<unsigned int, N>` to represent the size when creating/deleting, as well as the index when you're indexing into one).